How can I use the Ocrad.js script into my chrome extension?
I am trying to use the ocrad.js library to perform OCR, and it is throwing an error when I try to use it. I am able to load the script in properly, but I keep getting this error: "Uncaught (in promise) EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*"."
I believe this is because ocrad.js has eval() functions in it and MV3 doesn't allow this. I don't know how to get around this.

Is this in a content script?

Yes it is in my content.js script.

You can use chrome.userScripts API which currently requires the user to enable developer mode. Another method is to do it inside a sandboxed iframe: 1) Declare frame.html in web_accessible_resources, 2) Declare frame.html as sandbox 3) Use OCR scripts in frame.html, 4) In your content script add an iframe element with src = chrome.runtime.getURL('frame.html'), then use iframe.contentWindow.postMessage to send data.

Would I need to use a screen (frame.html) in order for the OCR to work? Because currently, the way the extension is meant to work is the content script works without any screen or html being open and is able to run in the background.

The iframe can be either a part of the web page or inside the invisible offscreen document.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
